# Accelerometer returning fixed values in sensorsimulator

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to use SensorSimulator in android. I installed the sensorsimulator apk and started the jar file. I can see that the two are connected as changes made for accelerometer in the desktop app reflects in android emulator ( say yaw, pitch etc.). However when I run my app it doesn't reflect any changes. In fact I get fixed values from accelerometer all the time. Do I need to add anything to my program to get the accelerometer running?